# GORM not returning data when querying a table that contains a column which is encrypted using Jasypt. (Grails)

Tags: encryption, grails, jasypt

I have used jasypt to encrypt a column in database, now when I am querying that table with that column using (GORM) findBy or creating a criteria, I am not getting any results. Encryption is done at domain level.

static mapping = {
        value type: GormEncryptedStringType
    }

Comment: it's a bad practice to perform a lookup against the encrypted column.

Comment: yes I understand, but this is a requirement in a scenario. is it possible anyhow ?

Comment: This was something I delved into last year and hit same issues. The short answer is no - Please review this project https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-encrypt-db-fields. Please feel free to download and mess around as you feel. But without forward walking i.e. first getting the objects that go through which ever transformation to get to be decrypted which could potentially be too expensive depending  on size of DB

Comment: @Vahid - Thanks a lot! Will go through this.